# Korach's progeny

Tags: levites-leviyim, pinchas, parshat-korach

In Parshas Pinchas it says that the children of Korach did not die. Is there anyone alive today that is aware that they are from the descendents of Korach?

Comment: Patrilineally?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Ben Achar Ben would be more interesting, however even in general I am interested if anyone is aware that they descend from Korach.

Comment: Is anyone nowadays who is aware of coming from Merari?

Answer (score 5):

In high school, I had a rebbe (Rabbi Horowitz) who said that he was a Korach Levi, part of a group that traced their lineage to Korach. And that they referred to the (somewhat misunderstood) Korach as 'the Heilige zeideh Korach'.

Comment: Was he related to the Shlah Hakadosh?

Comment: I understood that the sons of Korach were singers / composers during th etime of the Bet hamikdash? Was your rebbe a good singer?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Given that he had the same last name as the Shlah, I would say most likely.

Comment: @DanF It never came up.

Comment: @joshwaxman not all Horowitzes are related.

Comment: ah, didn't read carefully. i read into your comment that the Shlah was descended from Korach, and worked from there.